# Shell script to read range of files?

Tags: bash, shell

I have created 1000 files with names: 15_file1, 15_file2...15_file1000.

I wish to read only 300 files from 15_file1 to 15_file300.

I have a shell script:

```
fmount=/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount/ifm/Dir1/*

for myFiles in $fmount
do
      cat $myFiles  2>&1 | tee -a readFile.log &
done
```

But this will read all files, how to read only 300 out of them with that pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eliminate the use of the variable, and say:

```
for myFiles in /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount/ifm/Dir1/15_file{1..300}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell for loop :

```
for i in {1..10}
> do
> echo $i
> done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: How will this validate the number is less than 500?